# Strange plots by Mathematica

Tags: plotting

I think the picture speak for itself. Why is the x axis at y=1?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Because `Show` takes the options from the first plot (`v1`). Add `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}` to `Show`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this Domen!